# Triple noun, plural and ownership apostrophe

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

Been asked to write "x is good for your Customer's vehicle interior". I feel this should be "Customers' vehicle interiors" but am spinning in circles on it. Can you help break the stalemate in my head?!

Comment: The use of the singular is thinking of each customer as an individual.

Comment: Both are fine. The singular refers to each customer whereas the plural refers to them as a group.

Comment: Thanks both! Makes sense.